# Hanging program after clicking on start button

Tags: python, sockets, oop, kivy

in this code i create two clases one is for my gui (class me) and soc is for when the button start clicked the socket then should listen to local host in port 8080.When i run the progarm and clicked the start button it worked and idle showed me the listening message but then the program hanged.
[image: screenshot of hanging]

---

**what problem is in this code that cause this hanging?**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import socket

class soc():
     def __init__(self,s,conn, addr):

          self.s=s
          self.conn=conn
          self. addr= addr
          self.s=socket.socket()
          self.s.bind(('localhost',8080))
     def listen(self,click):
          self.s.listen()
          print ('listening...')
          
          self.conn,self. addr=self.s.accept()
          
soc=soc('s','conn','addr')

class me(App):
     def __init__(self,b,g,l,t):
          super(me, self).__init__()     
          self.b=Button(text='start',on_press =soc.listen)
          self.g=GridLayout(cols=4)
          self.l=Label(text='label')
          self.t=TextInput()
          
     def build(self):
          
          self.g.add_widget(self.b)
          self.g.add_widget(self.t)
          self.g.add_widget(self.l)
          return self.g

m=me('b','g','l','t')

m.run()
```

Comment: Where is the part in your code wherein click event on the button creates a socket?

Comment: self.b=Button(text='start',on_press =soc.listen)

Comment: `self. addr` Is this a typo in `listen()` - extra space?

Comment: My guess is that it hangs because of `accept()` which seems to be a blocking call.

Comment: No there won't be errors, it will just wait until there is a connection request - at least that's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your `listen()` method in a different thread. Use something like:

```
Thread(target=self.listen).start()
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/threading.html#thread-objects). Running `listen()` on the main thread holds that thread and prevents the GUI from updating.